# Is it some bizarre heresy to use classes without objects?

Tags: php, class

This may be a silly question, but it's been bugging me.

I've been writing what I believe to be procedural code, but I'm using classes which group together related public and private functions according to purpose. Instead of using objects and methods, I call the functions when needed with a scope resolution operator. ie: `db::execute($sql)`

I know it's ridiculous, but I just now realized everyone immediately associates classes with OOP. Am I committing some perverted heresy?

Comment: You are calling your methods statically.

Comment: Thanks -- I honestly had no idea what this practice was called. (no sarcasm)

Comment: This heathen thought calls for a major blood offering ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're basically abusing one language construct (class) to emulate another one (namespace). This is totally normal, as long as you use a language that doesn't support the latter (php 5.2-).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the distinction between classes and "OOP use of classes" then I guess it is not a real problem ...

Answer (score 2):

"Perverted heresy" might be taking it a little far, but you're certainly missing out on much of the organizational power of object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're using classes as namespaces.

I don't see anything particularly wrong with this - it provides logical separation of concerns, and presumably makes things easier for you to develop/maintain.

You'd definitely be better off learning more about Object-Oriented Programming so you can take advantage of the benefits it offers.

Comment: That's basically it. It made sense in an organization way, so I just went with it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't claim to be doing OOP, I don't see anything wrong with using static methods for procedural programming to make up for PHP's lack of namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong.

Some classes are used only to contain utility functions (for example the `Arrays` class in Java), actually called "static methods".

What you are doing is using this feature in substitution of namespaces. For clarity you should use the latter.